# C# / .NET socket connection for multiple parts with same IP / socket binding to network card/ip

Tags: c#, .net, tcpclient

We have 2 PCB's we want to send data to individually, both PCB share the same IP and same Port (192.168.249.2:4000).
Now the only difference its that PCB1 its connected to "Ethernet1" card on my PC and  PCB2 its connected to "Etherne2t".

```
PC---------Ethernet 1 (ip 192.168.249.11) ---------- PCB 1 ( ip:192.168.249.2:4000)
PC---------Ethernet 2 (ip 192.168.249.12) ---------- PCB 2 ( ip:192.168.249.2:4000)
```

How can i bind the code from beyond to only send data to the PCB via Eth1 or Eth2 ?

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.IO;

namespace tbxComSrv
{
    [ComVisible(true), GuidAttribute("C905E3B5-4F39-4a29-871C-2E32AA98EE43")]


    public interface ICom
    {
        uint upload(string filename, int port, string ip, int timeout);
        string getErrMsg();
        byte[] getResponse();
    }
    [ComVisible(true), GuidAttribute("B3CF3330-820A-46de-AC42-32BAAB963739")]
    [ProgId("TBX.App")]


    public class TBX: ICom
    {

        string ErrMsg;
        byte[] receiveBytes = new byte[6];
        public string getErrMsg()
        {
            if (ErrMsg == null)
                return "No Error";
            else 
                return ErrMsg;

        }


        public byte[] getResponse()
        {

            return receiveBytes;


        }



        public uint upload(string filename,int port, string ip, int timeout)
        {
            int addressBytesNumber = 4;
            int CheckSum_Bytes = 0;

            byte[] ff = File.ReadAllBytes(filename); // this holds all bytes from the toolbox file
                                                  
            Int32 dataSize = (ff[5] << 24) | (ff[4] << 16) | (ff[3] << 8) | ff[2]; // read data size from toolbox 

            byte[] out_buffer = new byte[dataSize + 2 + addressBytesNumber + CheckSum_Bytes];

            // first 4 bytes indicate how much data we send via ethernet
            out_buffer[0] = (byte)(dataSize & 0x000000FF); // LSB
            out_buffer[1] = (byte)((dataSize & 0x0000FF00) >> 8);
            out_buffer[2] = (byte)((dataSize & 0x00FF0000) >> 16);
            out_buffer[3] = (byte)((dataSize & 0xFF000000) >> 24); // MSB
            out_buffer[0] = (byte)(out_buffer[0] + 2 + addressBytesNumber + CheckSum_Bytes); // add extra 2 bytes

            Int32 bufferSize = (out_buffer[3] << 24) | (out_buffer[2] << 16) | (out_buffer[1] << 8) | out_buffer[0];


            Int32 j = 0;

            for (Int32 i = 4; i < bufferSize; i++)
            {
                out_buffer[i] = ff[j];
                j++;
            }

         
            IPAddress iaddr = IPAddress.Parse(ip);
            IPEndPoint remote = new IPEndPoint(iaddr, port);
            Socket soc = new Socket(iaddr.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

            soc.ReceiveTimeout = timeout;
            soc.SendTimeout = timeout;
            soc.SendBufferSize = 0x0004FFFF;
            soc.ReceiveBufferSize = 4000;
            soc.NoDelay = true;



            try
            {
                soc.Connect(remote);
            
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                ErrMsg = "Socket Connection Error";
                soc.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                soc.Close();
                return 2;

            }

            try
            {
                int bytesSent = soc.Send(out_buffer);
            }
            catch (SocketException se)
            {
               
                ErrMsg = "Socket sending data Error";
                soc.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                soc.Close();
                return 3;
            }

            for (int v = 0; v < receiveBytes.Length; v++)
                                             receiveBytes[v] = 0;  // clear old values from receive buffer.... just in case

            try
            {
                int bytesRec = soc.Receive(receiveBytes);
              //  Console.WriteLine("Received " + bytesRec.ToString() + " bytes");
                soc.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                soc.Close();
                
            }
            catch (SocketException se)
            {
                soc.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                soc.Close();
                ErrMsg = "Socket read timeout Error";
                return 4;

            }
           return 0;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You should delete your other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63305264/c-sharp-net-socket-connection-for-multiple-parts-with-same-ip#comment111944576_63305264

Comment: I am not a network guy, but isn't it impossible for 2 devices to share the same IP address on the same network? These devices would need to be on separate networks if they had the same internal IP

Comment: To be honest its possible, we have to solution to write the software via Eth and we use a station and connect to 6 PCB's in the same time, now that aplication its external and for different data package, and as i saw its somehow binding the "ethernet1" (ip 192.168.249.11) to it so they all work independently. I was wondering how i could do the same via this com object. Maybe add one more input, the binding ip or something in order to go via it .... the question is "how". Anyway..

Comment: Why can't you define a specific IP address, or atleast a specific port per PCB? having to exact same IP addresses is asking for trouble